# C - How to point an array structure to a variable?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to make a variable which receives the array **format**, but not the exact value of the array position. How can I do that? The example below shows what I want to do (not that it is working anyway, just to show my intent).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, m = 30;
    double T[m][m], aE = 3, TE;

    TE = T[i][j+1];

    for (i = 1; i < 30; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < 30; j++)
            T[i][j] = (aE * TE);

    getch();
    return (0);
}
```

Ok, the array will have a lot of `double` values, and I want that the `TE` points or acts like the structure `T[i][j+i]` so that I can use `TE` every time I need that position of the `T` array.

How is this possible?

Comment: `double *TE; TE = &T[i][j+1];` But thats only for current `i` and `j` which you have not initialized and therefore is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don’t get what are you asking for, but in your code you initialize  TE = T[i][j+1] without initializing i nor j

Comment: It's not possible without macros. You can make `TE` point to a specific element, but if you update `i` or `j` then `TE` still points to the same element it pointed to before. *And* I think it's better to use `T[i][j+1]` explicitly as it really show what you want and are doing.

Comment: Whats the problem with just using `T[i][j+1]`?

Comment: You can't use 'm' as an array initialiser because it isn't a constance

Comment: What do you mean by *points or act like the structure "T[i][j+I]"*? `T[i][j+1]` is not a structure at all, it's just a `double`. Sometimes it's hard to know how to describe something when you're a little foggy on the details, but if you're not clear about what you want to do then we have little chance of helping you.

Comment: When `j=29`, `j+1=30`. `T[i][30]` is causing undefined behaviour, because it just left the index boundary... I am referring to the loop headline of the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your example that would provide it from being compiled (I guess it's maid to give us an idea of what the structure would look like). I'll try to write here a working version that would do something similar.

```
#ifdef MALLOC_ME

int i, j, m;
m = inputed_matrix_size;

double **T = malloc(sizeof(double) * m * m);

#else

# define MATRIX_SIZE 30
int i, j, m = MATRIX_SIZE;
double T[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

#endif // MALLOC_ME

// I'll assume we put some defined value in the first line, first column
// that will be used as source in later calculation.
T[0][0] = value;
double *TE = &T[0][0];
double aE = some_indice_value;

for (i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
  for (j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
  {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
      continue; // lets not override our template value;

    T[i][j] = aE * (*TE); 
    // *TE is the double value contained at the position of the array stored earlier
  }
```